# How can I pass a FormControl to a function from the template?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

Let's say I have this:

```
<input formControlName="someName" (click)="onClick()">
```

I want my `onClick` function to be generic and set the value of the corresponding `FormControl` (the one I clicked).

How can I pass the concerned `FormControl` as a parameter of `onClick`?

I thought I could retrieve it from the `control` property of [FormControlDirective](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective) or [FormControlName](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName) but none of them have an `exportAs` attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want to achieve.

```js
import { Directive, HostListener, Optional, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appOnClickControl]' // if you want to target specific form control then use custom selector else you use can use input:
                                   // selector: 'input' to target all input elements
})
export class TestDirective {
  @Output() emitFormControl = new EventEmitter<FormControl>();

  constructor(@Optional() private formControl: NgControl) {
  }


  /**
   * If your only goal is to set value to the form control  then use this
   */
  @HostListener('click')
  onClick() {
    if (this.formControl) {
      this.formControl.control.setValue('test');
    }
  }

  /**
   * If you wanna pass the form control through the function you might use this
   */
  @HostListener('click')
  getFormControl(): void {
      this.emitFormControl.emit(this.formControl.control as FormControl);
  }
}
```

```html
 <input
  appOnClickControl // use this to initialize directive
  (emitFormControl)="yourMethod($event)" // $event is the clicked form control
  formControlName="test"
></input>
```

Answer (score 4):

In your html:

```
<input formControlName="someName" (click)="onClick($event)">
```

And then define your onClick function as:

```
onClick(event): void {
 alert(event.target.value)
}
```

**Edit**
To get FormControl:

```
<input formControlName="someName" (click)="onClick(Form.get('someName'))">
```

and

```
onClick(formControl): void {
    formControl.setValue(someValue);
  }
```

Comment: I don't want the HTML element, I want the `FormControl`

Comment: Edited my answer to get FormControl

Answer (score 3):

kinda repetitive but pretty sure you can only do this:

```
<input formControlName="someName" (click)="onClick('someName')">
```

then use someName on your form group to find the control

```
onClick(name: string) {
  const fc = this.form.get(name);
  // do whatever
}
```

Comment: that suggests that I find the control in the `FormGroup` structure which is not necessarily `this.form.get(name)` (maybe nested in `FormGroup`, `FormArray`, etc...). So I can't have one unique generic implementation of `onClick`

Comment: You can pass names to get like “nested.property.name” to access nested forms

Comment: Still that does not allow `onClick` to be generic

Comment: it's roughly as generic as you're going to get in this situation without passing the form control in directly by calling get in the template, and I think it's better practice to do less in template and instead write an adapter function around your "generic" function

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you're after, but try if the following works for you. It uses [`setValue()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setvalue) method to set values for the form. You can also use [`patchvalue`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#patchvalue) if you want to set only partial values of the form.

Template

```
<form [formGroup]='groupedform' >
  <label>Name:  <br>
    <input type="text" formControlName='Name' required (mousedown)="onMouseDown(groupedform)"/>
  </label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>Email:  <br>
    <input type="email" formControlName='Email' required (mousedown)="setEmail(groupedform)"/>
  </label>
  <p>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!groupedform.valid" (click)="updateName()">Update Name</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Component

```js
export class AppComponent  {
   name = 'Angular';
   firstname = new FormControl('');
   groupedform = this.fb.group({
    Name : ['', Validators.required],
    Email: [],
  });

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) { }

  updateName() {
    console.log(this.groupedform.value);
  }

  onMouseDown(formControl: any) {
    this.groupedform.setValue({
      'Name': 'sample',
      'Email': 'sample@example.com'
    });
  }

  setEmail(formControl: any) {
    this.groupedform.patchValue({
      'Email': 'sample@example.com'
    });
  }
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-control-concepts-uqnhod)

Answer (score 0):

> You can use template variable for this

```
<input formControlName="someName" #temp (click)="onClick(temp)">

onClick(val) {
console.log(val);}
```

Comment: this will pass the input element in.  not the formControl

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what type of value you want to set, but you can use an attribute directive for this type of common operation (if it is simple).

You can create an attribute directive and set on all the form controls, the attribute directive logic will automatically handle it for you. You can definetely configure the values passed to directives.

import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Input } from "@angular/core";

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[clickMe]'
})
export class ClickDirective {
  @Input('clickMe') clickValue:string;
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef){}

  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = this.clickValue;
  }
}
```

Now just use these directives with the the form controls and pass your values, you can use data binding as well.

```
<form [formControl]="myForm">
  Firstname:<input type="text" fromControlName="firstname" [clickMe]="'first value'" />
<br>
Lastname:<input type="text" fromControlName="lastname" [clickMe]="'last value'" />
</form>
```

Please find the working stackblitz here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j1kwch

Answer (score 0):

You could use the event passed and get the attribute name out of it:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="yourName" (blur)="yourMethod($event)" />
```

Then in your method get the name of the `formControlName` from the target:

```
yourMethod(event: any) {
  const controlName = e.target.getAttribute('formcontrolname');
  this.formGroup.get(controlName); // this is your FormControl
  ....
}
```